# Как сделать ширину и высоту ссылки, как у родителя в адаптивной верстке?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не понятно, как наследовать ширину и высоту для ссылки от родительского элемента. Буду благодарен за помощь:)

```css
.image_blocks {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(325px,1fr));
}

.image_block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.image_block>img {
    width: 100%;
}

.image_block>a {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="image_blocks">
  <li class="image_block">
    <img src="image/1.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="">Nike Air</a>
  </li>
  <li class="image_block">
    <img src="image/2.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="">Air Jordan</a>
  </li>
  <li class="image_block">
    <img src="image/3.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="">Yeezy Boost</a>
  </li>
  <li class="image_block">
    <img src="image/4.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="">Nike Air</a>
  </li>
  <li class="image_block">
    <img src="image/5.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="">Air Jordan</a>
  </li>
  <li class="image_block">
    <img src="image/6.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="">Yeezy Boost</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inherit
```

Устанавливает значение свойства, применённого к элементу, таким же, как у его родительского элемента. Фактически, это "включает наследование".
Пример:

**CSS:**

```
body {
    color: green;
}
          
.my-class-1 a {
    color: inherit;
}
          
.my-class-2 a {
    color: initial;
}
          
.my-class-3 a {
    color: unset;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Default <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
    <li class="my-class-1">Inherit the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
    <li class="my-class-2">Reset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
    <li class="my-class-3">Unset the <a href="#">link</a> color</li>
</ul>
```

Источник: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance

Comment: Проблема в том, что не наследуется ширина и высота!

Comment: @Zahar `.image_block>a { width: inherit; height: inherit}`

Comment: Проблема в отсутствии google на вашем пк.
И я на вскидку скажу убрать position: absolute, этот параметр не дает наследовать у родителя свойства. 
http://shpargalkablog.ru/2015/06/inherit-initial-unset-css.html

Comment: уберите абсолютное позиционирование.

Comment: А как тогда мне расположить ссылку по середине относительно родительского блока?

Comment: display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center; 
Например

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position отличный пример как ведет себя элемент с абсолютным позиционированием. Я бы с ним не частил. (тут могу быть не прав) Избегал бы его по началу

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Comment: Не за что. Удачи в изучении